# htaccess multiple query string redirects to different urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am totally new to attempting redirects in htaccess but have a list of about 20 urls, all with query strings and all going to different urls.

I have managed to get a redirect using a query string working using RewriteCond and RewriteRule but when I add the other urls in the same format they all seem to redirect to the url in the first RewriteRule.

Its getting so frustrated as I have searched everywhere and tried so many ways to try and get this working. Hopefully someone on here can help me!

Here are a couple of the urls I need to redirect:

/store/index.php?search=flip flops >> http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk/menswear/flip-flops

/store/index.php?search=Boss+Orange+Shorts >> http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk/menswear/shorts

And here is the code I have got so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING} search=flip flops" 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk/menswear/flip-flops/? [R=301,N]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} search=Boss+Orange+Shorts 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk/menswear/shorts? [R=301,N]
```

(plus the rest of the rewrites in the same format)

Each of these are getting redirected to the flip flops page!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use of flag `N` you need `L` flag instead. Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING} search=flip flops" [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/index\.php$ http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk//menswear/flip-flops/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=Boss\+Orange\+Shorts(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/index\.php$ http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk/menswear/shorts/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. Its not worked for me unfortunately.

Although, I realized a mistake in my own code, I am guessing the rule should start with /store/index rather than just index. How would I incorporate that into what you have just suggested.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't redirecting at all now, its just continuing to bring up the old page.

Comment: Still no joy! Its still not even attempting to redirect.

Comment: I had tested the code to be working fine, before posting the latest answer.

Comment: Still not working for me, just taking me to the old page still. Cleared cash and everything too. Ahh well, thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out for you and its very difficult for me to guess why this working code doesn't work on your host. Just make sure mod_rewrite, .htaccess etc are enabled and working.

Answer (score 0):

You have some small syntax errors here.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^search=flip flops$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/index\.php$ http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk/menswear/flip-flops/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=Boss\+Orange\+Shorts$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/index\.php$ http://www.stonemenswear.co.uk/menswear/shorts/? [R=301,L]
```